# Filter on an element of an array will cast the right hand side to array

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am having a hard time with filtering on arrays elements using Django (with a PostgreSQL table)
Suppose I have a model MyModel with a field my_array which contains, say, booleans (the type does not really matter)
I want to check that the first element of my array is True.

For me the natural way was to do

```
MyModel.objects.filter(bool_array__0=True)
```

however this generates the following SQL filter

```
... WHERE bool_array[1] = true::boolean[]
```

Problem here is that django automatically casts the right hand side to `boolean[]` and ends up with comparing `boolean` to `boolean[]`.

I have tried with the `__in` lookup, and putting `[True]` instead of `True` but doesn't work either.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you show how you declare your `ArrayField` ?

Comment: I suspect you followed the documentation and nested your array with another array..

Comment: You nailed it indeed, I have `my_array = ArrayField(base_field=ArrayField(base_field=models.FloatField()))` but it's chosen to be able to support kind of 2 dim arrays (in my situation nevertheless I can assert I have only one dim, ie my_array = bool[] and not bool[][]

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField.base_field) of `ArrayField` could be misleading:

> ```
> from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
> from django.db import models
>
> class ChessBoard(models.Model):
>     board = ArrayField(
>         ArrayField(
>             models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True),
>             size=8,
>         ),
>         size=8,
>     )
> ```

If you don't pay attention, you'll have a nested array. In your model, you should be declaring:

```
my_array = ArrayField(base_field=models.BooleanField())
```

In order to have a plain array of booleans.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very relevant answer Ben. Thing is in my case I cannot change how `my_array` is declared as it needs to support both 1d and 2d arrays. 
I guess I'll have to use RawSQL here.

Side note: I'm a bit surprised actually that with the defition of `my_array`, I still have values like `[{'my_array': [20.0, 20.0]}]` (and not [[20, 20]]) when I query my model (in django shell)

Comment: That's because, you use `FloatField`. Maybe you should use an `IntegerField` ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I read again and understand your point. The question is how you input your data ?